# Ramanujan's construction of $\left(9^2+\frac{19^2}{22}\right)^\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: geometry

In Ramanujan's "Modular equations and approximations to $\pi$" (pp.43-44) he gives a geometric construction of the formula in the title. I tried to prove it but couldn't and then did the construction in GeoGebra and obtained for OS the value $1.1$ instead of the inteneded $\pi/3\approx 1.047$. I must be doing the construction incorrectly, but I can't see how. Attached are Ramanujan's construction and a screenshot of the GeoGebra construction.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to take the "mean proportional between OS and OB" to get to the result, i.e. $\frac{OS+1}{2}$. Let me know if this solves the issue

Comment: thanks. I never heard the phrase "mean proportional", but it is the geometric mean, not the arithmetic mean: $\sqrt{OS\cdot OB}$. The numbers work out OK: $\sqrt{1.0967}=1.0472\approx \pi/3$.

Comment: Glad you fixed the problem.

Comment: @Moti If you could answer your own question and accept it, that would be great :)

Comment: Please see my addition to the question from 29 March.